# Запрос sudo на выполнение скрипта (ранее введенные данные пропадают)

Tags: shell, sudo

Пишу скрипт, который в процессе выполнения запросит авторизацию суперпользователя и продолжит выполнение.
У меня ошибка при запросе прав, но не могу понять в какой момент она происходит.
Дело в том, что переменная `TS_DIRECTORY` обнуляет введенные ранее данные после запроса прав `sudo`. Прошу помощи:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

SRC_PATH=$(pwd)/build
PACKAGES=./packages.list
read -ep "Путь расположения корневого каталога: " TS_DIRECTORY
DST_PATH=$TS_DIRECTORY/build

if [ "$(id -nu)" != "root" ]; then
    sudo --reset-timestamp
    read -sp "Для выполнения необходимо ввести пароль суперпользователя: " PASSWORD
    exec sudo --stdin --prompt '' "$0" "$@" <<< "$PASSWORD"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e $TS_DIRECTORY ]; then
    echo "Указанной директории не существует!"
    exit 1
fi

echo $TS_DIRECTORY
echo $DST_PATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то сложно вы всё делаете, зачем-то пароль через `read` запрашиваете, а после пытаетесь его втиснуть в `sudo`, ради чего ? красивую надпись можно и с помощью того же ключа --prompt вывести.

Потом, если вам нужно чтобы скрипт работал от суперпользователя то почему проверку не сделать в начале скрипта ? Вот запустили скрипт от простого пользователя, ввели корневой каталог, а потом оказалось что пользователь не супер, и что теперь ? опять вводить данные по новой ? тот же корневой каталог.

Вот немного пригладил ваш скрипт до рабочего состояния

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPT=$(realpath "$0")
DIR=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")

if [ "$USER" != "root" ]; then
    sudo --reset-timestamp
    exec sudo --prompt 'Для выполнения необходимо ввести пароль суперпользователя: ' "$SCRIPT" "$@"
    exit 1
fi

until [ -e "$TS_DIRECTORY"  ]; do
    read -ep "Путь расположения корневого каталога: " TS_DIRECTORY
done
DST_PATH="$TS_DIRECTORY/build"
PACKAGES="$DIR/packages.list"
SRC_PATH="$DIR/build"
```

хотя лучше вообще так не делать и не использовать внутри скрипта вызов `sudo` и подобных *разрешающих* утилит. Если скрипт делаете не только для себя но и для других то нету никакой гарантии что у пользователя вообще установлен `sudo` или возможно вообще используется како-то другой аналог, например `doas`.

Верным решением будет после проверки на наличие прав суперпользователя завершить скрипт и вывести предупреждение о том что в доступе отказанно ( ... : **permission denied** ).

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Скрипт не для массового использования, специфический, для конкретного дистрибутива.